# how would you explain following javascript snippet?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope, closures

```js
function d() {
  console.log(j)
}

let e = () => console.log(j);

(function() {
  let j = 3;
  d();
  e();
})();
```

It will log 3 for both function execution.

So can we assume, that whenever a javascript function executes, it will try to resolve the variable from parent scope, if not in current scope?

Comment: `j is not defined` that's all you will get from this code snippet

Comment: `d` and `e` are not defined in the same scope as `j`.  They are executed from that scope.  It's not the same.

Answer (score 0):

A closure is formed when a function is declared inside another function not when the function is called inside another function.

Or you can say.

The variables available to function are the those which are declared in their parent function where they are declared not where they are called.

Answer (score 0):

Both `console.log(j)` use `j` from the scope where it is defined, not from where the functions are called.